# How to check the conditon whether a number has letters and digits that are greater than 10 using shell script

Tags: shell, sh, time-format

how to check both conditions in shell script, that whether a number has alphabets and that number should not consist of more than 10 digits

```
re='[a-zA-Z]'
read -p "Enter time:" epoch_time

if [[ "$epoch_time" =~ $re ]] -a [[ "${#time}" -gt 10 ]];then
         echo "not a valid time"
else
        echo "entered time is valid"
fi
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how to check a both conditions in shell script that whether a number has alphabets and that number should not consists of more than 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

You can write your regular expression to validate just for numbers and to check for input length.

```
re='^[0-9]+{0,10}$'; read -p "Enter time:" epoch_time
if [[ $epoch_time =~ $re ]]; then echo "entered time is valid"; else "not valid time" fi
```

Comment: The regular expression checks whether the string has a maximum number of 10 characters